# How can I create a “CLI Kiosk” before login?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, autologin, kiosk

I have a bash script that runs screen that displays various things like htop and some output from a MQTT server.

I currently have no GUI installed and this runs on the command line on Ubuntu Server. I also have to login manually on each startup and run the script.

Is it possible to create a user account that automatically logs in on startup and then automatically runs this script? Quitting the script should allow me to type exit and logout as that user (to login as admin). The account should have no other permissions. It's basically a CLI kiosk. Is this easy to do?

Comment: [Auto-login on Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/a/819154/10371) was easy to find. I'm not sure what "this" is here – I certainly wouldn't expect this to be easy to do *securely,* for example. Are you OK with something which can be trivially broken by a passer-by or do you need it to be in any way resilient to tampering?

Comment: @l0b0 it's okay if they try to run commands with the kiosk account. As long as my admin/root account is safe. The kiosk account will have only enough permissions to whatever the the script needs and to logoff.